# Vertical spacing around equations. Problem with \abovedisplayshortskip

Tags: equations, vertical-spacing

I am confused about spacing around equations.

Perhaps I misread it but my understanding is the following `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip` would control vertical spacing/glue around equations. The first is supposed to apply when the last line of a paragraph overlaps the equation underneath the line. Otherwise, the second would apply.

In this MWE below, I expected the second equation would move upwards due to `-X\baselineskip` as the line does not overlap the equation but it is not applied.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\newcommand\mathexpr{%
    \begin{align*}f(x) = \sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2} \end{align*}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{\baselineskip}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{-10\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason of things.
\mathexpr

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation.
\mathexpr

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason of things.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMS alignments are always full width, so the shortskip is never used.

If you try it with `\[\]` then you see the effect:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\newcommand\mathexpr{\[x=y\]}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \setlength\lineskiplimit{-100pt}
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{\baselineskip}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{-10\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason of things.
\mathexpr

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation.
\mathexpr

As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason of things.


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\[...\]` the equivalence of `equation` environment? I have a lot of equations inside `align`, some of them are long and only particular equation lines are numbered. I guess I would insert `aligned` in `\[\]` but how can I number particular equations-lines, then?

Comment: If it's cannot work using simple solution then I'd probably better of accepting the default spacing. Thanks

Comment: Just one more question. By any chance, do you know of any workaround to obtain similar effects?

Comment: `\[` isthe standard latex environment for an unnumbered equation, with `amsmath` you can also access it as `\begin{equation*}` you should always use this and not `align` for single line equations with (therefore) no alignment, ie equations as in your example.